# Openshift - Spring Boot - Error creating new application - Failed to execute: 'control start'

Tags: spring-boot, openshift

I am trying to deploy a very simple Spring-Boot application on Openshift.
I am creating **Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) Cartridge** using openshift online from browser.

I am getting following errors while creating it. 
[image]

and

[image]
Could not find any solution for that. Could someone help that what is going wrong here.

Git URL: https://github.com/bhaskey/testingcloud

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the exact reason for error. However I find following issues in you code.

- Java Version Not sure if JBoss EWS 2.0 supports  1.7(In generated pom.xml deafults to 1.7)
- You are deploying on Tomcat server, however `spring-boot-starter-web` has transitive dependency on `spring-boot-starter-tomcat`. You need to set tomcat dependency to provided.
- Your packing is jar and you've spring boot maven plugin not sure, how it is going to be deploy to tomcat server's webapps directory. it uses openshift profile to build the project. and your openshift profile might not work as expected.
- In order for spring boot to run on external app server, you need to extend your main class with `extends SpringBootServletInitializer`

---

However I would suggest you to follow  these steps to create spring boot project deployable to openshift.

1. Create Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) Cartridge from web console or Eclipse openshift plugin.
2. Clone the project to your local machine.
3. Modify pom.xml, add spring boot parent dependency and add only dependencies. Leave plugin as it is.
   The updated pom.xml would look something like this.

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.openshif</groupId>
   <artifactId>cloudemo</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <name>cloudemo</name>
   <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
       <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>eap</id>
           <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
           <releases>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
       <pluginRepository>
           <id>eap</id>
           <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
           <releases>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
   <properties>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
       <java.version>1.6</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <profiles>
       <profile>
           <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
               invoking mvn. -->
           <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
               will need. -->
           <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
               folder. -->
           <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
           <id>openshift</id>
           <build>
               <finalName>cloudemo</finalName>
               <plugins>
                   <plugin>
                       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>2.1.1</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                           <warName>ROOT</warName>
                       </configuration>
                   </plugin>
               </plugins>
           </build>
       </profile>
   </profiles>
   ```
4. Modify MainClass file

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class CloudemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {


   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

       return builder.sources(CloudemoApplication.class);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(CloudemoApplication.class, args);
   }
   ```
5. Since your application doesn't use spring boot plugin you might need to place all your html, css, js resources under webapps directory

Comment: Thank you sir for answering in such detail. I will try working in this way.